# ISOTOPE - 2 grids on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery-isotope

I am trying to implement 2 different isotope grids filter + pagination on one page and have issues setting up the second one.
As you can see on my pen, the first one is working and not the second one. I used the same id and class for both grid and think the issue is there but I couldn't manage to update my javascript to make it work!
Could someone help me with that?

Thanks

https://codepen.io/tcosteur/pen/oNWoNWP

here is my js:

```
function cbChange(obj) {
    var cbs = document.getElementsByClassName("filter-item");
    for (var i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
        cbs[i].checked = false;
    }
    obj.checked = true;
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    // filter items on button click
    $('.filter-button-group').on('click', 'li', function() {
        var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $('.grid').isotope({
            filter: filterValue
        });
        $('.filter-button-group li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
})

var itemSelector = ".item";
var $checkboxes = $('.filter-item');
var $container = $('#products').isotope({
    itemSelector: itemSelector
});

//Ascending order
var responsiveIsotope = [
    [480, 4],
    [720, 6]
];
var itemsPerPageDefault = 8;
var itemsPerPage = defineItemsPerPage();
var currentNumberPages = 1;
var currentPage = 1;
var currentFilter = '*';
var filterAttribute = 'data-filter';
var filterValue = "";
var pageAttribute = 'data-page';
var pagerClass = 'isotope-pager';

// update items based on current filters    
function changeFilter(selector) {
    $container.isotope({
        filter: selector
    });
}

//grab all checked filters and goto page on fresh isotope output
function goToPage(n) {
    currentPage = n;
    var selector = itemSelector;
    var exclusives = [];
    // for each box checked, add its value and push to array
    $checkboxes.each(function(i, elem) {
        if (elem.checked) {
            selector += (currentFilter != '*') ? '.' + elem.value : '';
            exclusives.push(selector);
        }
    });
    // smash all values back together for 'and' filtering
    filterValue = exclusives.length ? exclusives.join('') : '*';

    // add page number to the string of filters
    var wordPage = currentPage.toString();
    filterValue += ('.' + wordPage);

    changeFilter(filterValue);
}

// determine page breaks based on window width and preset values
function defineItemsPerPage() {
    var pages = itemsPerPageDefault;

    for (var i = 0; i < responsiveIsotope.length; i++) {
        if ($(window).width() <= responsiveIsotope[i][0]) {
            pages = responsiveIsotope[i][1];
            break;
        }
    }
    return pages;
}

function setPagination() {

    var SettingsPagesOnItems = function() {
        var itemsLength = $container.children(itemSelector).length;
        var pages = Math.ceil(itemsLength / itemsPerPage);
        var item = 1;
        var page = 1;
        var selector = itemSelector;
        var exclusives = [];
        // for each box checked, add its value and push to array
        $checkboxes.each(function(i, elem) {
            if (elem.checked) {
                selector += (currentFilter != '*') ? '.' + elem.value : '';
                exclusives.push(selector);
            }
        });
        // smash all values back together for 'and' filtering
        filterValue = exclusives.length ? exclusives.join('') : '*';
        // find each child element with current filter values
        $container.children(filterValue).each(function() {
            // increment page if a new one is needed
            if (item > itemsPerPage) {
                page++;
                item = 1;
            }
            // add page number to element as a class
            wordPage = page.toString();

            var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
            var lastClass = classes[classes.length - 1];
            // last class shorter than 4 will be a page number, if so, grab and replace
            if (lastClass.length < 4) {
                $(this).removeClass();
                classes.pop();
                classes.push(wordPage);
                classes = classes.join(' ');
                $(this).addClass(classes);
            } else {
                // if there was no page number, add it
                $(this).addClass(wordPage);
            }
            item++;
        });
        currentNumberPages = page;
    }();

    // create page number navigation
    var CreatePagers = function() {

        var $isotopePager = ($('.' + pagerClass).length == 0) ? $('<div class="' + pagerClass + '"></div>') : $('.' + pagerClass);

        $isotopePager.html('');
        if (currentNumberPages > 1) {
            for (var i = 0; i < currentNumberPages; i++) {
                var $pager = $('<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="pager" ' + pageAttribute + '="' + (i + 1) + '"></a>');
                $pager.html(i + 1);

                $pager.click(function() {
                    var page = $(this).eq(0).attr(pageAttribute);
                    goToPage(page);
                });
                $pager.appendTo($isotopePager);
            }
        }
        $container.after($isotopePager);
    }();
}
// remove checks from all boxes and refilter
function clearAll() {
    $checkboxes.each(function(i, elem) {
        if (elem.checked) {
            elem.checked = null;
        }
    });
    currentFilter = '*';
    setPagination();
    goToPage(1);
}

setPagination();
goToPage(1);

//event handlers
$checkboxes.change(function() {
    var filter = $(this).attr(filterAttribute);
    currentFilter = filter;
    setPagination();
    goToPage(1);
});

$('#clear-filters').click(function() {
    clearAll()
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    itemsPerPage = defineItemsPerPage();
    setPagination();
    goToPage(1);
});
```